# How to verify user using Angular JS and JWT?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt

I am currently working on registration module. I am able to register using a form. I am using Angular JS for frontend and Nodejs for backend services. I call the API and thus it gets registered. After registering, the user gets a verification mail upon which clicking the button, the user should be successfully verified.

I have achieved till sending a mail but after clicking on 'verify button' in mail it lands onto login page directly without verifying. I want to verify the user and send the token to the verify API. I am not sure about how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use node jwt module which solve your problem.
When user login then create token for user

var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
              expiresIn: '1440m' // expires in 24 hours
   });

Then sent token with response each time when user try to access any url create middle-ware that will verify user token it is valid or not.

```
    /* Middle-ware to verify toke */
    apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x- access-token'];
  // decode token
  if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ status: 102, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: I need it for registration not for login. I need to send the token to verify api for verification

Comment: Generate another token when user register with different  value of   superSecret                var token = jwt.sign(admin, app.get('superSecret'), {
                        expiresIn: '1440m' // expires in 24 hours
                    }); then create middleware to check this token value with same superSecret set at time of registration.

Comment: is this the node code as I have to work only the frontend part using angular

Comment: At backend you are using nodejs.send this token with link of verify email.
All this is node stuff.

Comment: Yes i do get a mail with the link saying "verify your email". But when I click on it, it doesnt verify. It directly lands into login page

Comment: You have to implement all stuff on backend. when you hit registration api then from back end you have send a mail with verify link including token and also create middleware at backend to verify token.

Comment: so you mean to say there is nothing to do in frontend side. not even sending the token to api for verification/

Comment: Yes, you can use angular-jwt for this

Comment: do you know how to do it?

Comment: No,I did not used it.